# A widget application that shows live score of Barclays Premier League

Tags: android, android-widget

Trying to develop a widget on the Android Platform. I find a lot of widgets for the English or Barclays premier league but they are complex. What I would want is just a score of the ongoing match on the android mobile home screen. On tap of that if any goals are scored the details with name of the player who scored and the minute in which he scored on the home screen of the app...Have gone through this [Android: Help with widget that shows news](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430701/android-help-with-widget-that-shows-news)...

I have moved ahead on this.....I ve got my layouts and Service working......what now I want is any API for the premier league exposed so that I could integrate into my app..???

Comment: Your question is way to broad. Please refine it by indicating what it is you're having problems with.

Comment: Hi THelper, I followed the tutorial - http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html...I want to add an img source on the layout...I could not do that...where and how do i add that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tutorial the layout is defined in the

> widget_layout.xml file under the folder "res/layout".

To add an image add something like this

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/widget_image"
    android:src="@drawable/yourimage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />
```

where "yourimage" should be replaced with the name of an image in your `res/drawable` folder.

Make sure the current TextView isn't getting in the way of your image. You may want to remove the TextView, or change it's layout settings. Alternatively, if you want to keep the TextView and just add an image as a background you just add the following to the TextView:

```
android:background="@drawable/yourimage"
```

Comment: THelper have integrated this with the app...Removed TextView and the dependent codes for it. Compiles fine...but when I try to run it, It says Problem Loading Widget...any thing on this ::|

Comment: This means there is an error in your code. Check logcat to find out what exactly.

Comment: There seems to be a problem if I add an EditText...the widget does not accept it and the logcat does not give any details abt the error

Comment: Sorry THelper....I looked into the LogCat again and found out the error for edittext is this android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.widget.EditText

Comment: EditTexts are not allowed on widgets, only the classes listed [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the API your best option might be to use the fantasy football official premier league API. My understanding is that there is no documentation for the official API, which can be accessed by hitting this URL, where '#' is a number between 1 and the total amount of players (550 at the time of writing):

http://fantasy.premierleague.com/web/api/elements/#/

This gives a JSON object of the player (number) being requested.

There is also an unofficial API, which I haven't tried yet, but it looks to have done a lot of the hard work for you:

http://hackersome.com/p/bobbymond/FantasyPremierLeagueAPI